# How to request focus for recycle view under Scrollview

Tags: android, kotlin

I have scroll view and recycle view(separately) in constraintLayout. I want to requestFocus programmatically for recycleView when view is created but I cannot, despite I use .requestView() the focus is on scrollView.

Scrollview is above recycleView.

Answer (score 0):

If u want the recyclerview being above the scrollview u just have to switch your scrollview and your recycler in your constaintlayout.

Comment: I don't want that. I want like it is described, but I want initial focus on recycleView(it is button recycleView)

Comment: Can you share some code of the view please